How can I play Garry's Mod offline with backup-restored addons?
I own Garry's Mod on steam and run the x86-64 branch on macOS (any directories mentioned prefixed with ~/Library/Application Support/Steam).  I would like to restore my time machine backup of the steamapps/workshop directory so that I can enjoy addons which no longer exist in the steam workshop.
To ensure compatibility, I also restore the steamapps/common/GarrysMod directory from the same period in time machine.  I have been unable to load any of the addons content in-game because they seem to require validation via check-in with the workshop.  Here is what I have tried with subsequent attempts, while launching steam and garry's mod fully offline:

setting NeedsUpdate and NeedsDownload to 0, and TimeLastUpdated, TimeLastAppRan, and all appearances of timeupdated forward to current unix time, in steamapps/workshop/appworkshop_4000.acf with hopes that the client won't invalidate the addons for lack of internet connection
copying all .gma files from all directories at steamapps/workshop/content/4000 into steamapps/common/GarrysMod/garrysmod/addons in case this would exempt the addons from requiring workshop validation

In all cases, garry's mod launches fine but does not have any of the addons content enabled in-game.  I can see them from the addons menu, but none are enabled, and none will enable if I opt to select all and enable all from that menu either.
Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

What I've learned:

you cannot mount Garry's Mod addons stored at steamapps/workshop/content/4000 in-game without an internet connection to validate them
you can always mount Garry's Mod addons, including delisted workshop addons, if they are

decompressed from the .gma format (the format in which previously mounted workshop addons can be found within their nested directories at steamapps/workshop/content/4000) to the older addon format using the gmad program (here is a platform-agnostic version written in Python)

for a legacy workshop addon file ending in .bin, the prerequisite step would be to extract it first, (on macOS, The Unarchiver will work) and then append .gma to the file name


placed into steamapps/common/GarrysMod/garrysmod/addons (where each addon placed here is a decompressed directory, as would be the output from gmad)


with numerous "offline" addons in the above directory, I've found load times and performance to suffer greatly in-game; running the same addons loaded from your workshop directory (assuming they are available on the workshop) is significantly more performant; so it seems preferable to only mount offline addons if they aren't available on the workshop

